# How to calculate power delivered to an animal based on an equation from a journal article?

Tags: self-learning, unit-of-measure

I'm trying to replicate an equation from a paper (linked below but behind a paywall). The equation states that:

$\huge P = \frac{2em}{T+\frac{2r}{V}}$

where:

- e = 4.33 megajoules per kg
- m = 0.008 kg
- T = 24 hours
- r = 212 km
- V = 4.9 metres per second

P should equal .401 Watts in this case but I must be messing up my unit conversions because I can't get that. Hope you can help.

Scaling of Foraging Radius and Growth Rate in Petrels and Albatrosses (Procellariiformes) https://www.jstor.org/stable/3675955

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to transform all the units into $J,s,g,m$, so $$e=4330J/g$$ $$m = 8g$$ $$T=24h=86400s$$$$r=212000m$$ $$V=4.9m/s$$ Hence, $$P=\frac{2em}{T+\frac{2r}{V}}=\frac{2\cdot4330\cdot8}{86400+\frac{2\cdot 212000}{4.9}}=0.401 W$$